# Como llamar a un metodo de otra clase en typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

la cuestion es que tengo una clase A con sus atributos y un metodo "imprimir" que adentro contiene un console log.   como podria llamar a ese metodo desde otra clase?

```
class Personas{ 
 public Nombre:string; 
 public Apellido:string; 
 //public ape:string; 
 constructor(_Nombre:string,_Apellido:string){ this.Nombre=_Nombre; 
 this.Apellido=_Apellido; 
 } 
} 
 var objeto = new Telefono('cvc', 454441314); console.log(objeto);
```

agredeceria su ayuda :)

Comment: Nos muestras por favor tu código :), ¿el método es estático, estás haciendo herencia?

Comment: ya habías agregado tu código a un comentario, por favor edita tu pregunta y ahi escribelo, si requieres apoyo para el proceso no dudes en avisar

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacerlo a través de:

- Crear la herencia de una clase que depende de la principal que contiene por dentro a dicho método
- Haces la instancia de la clase dependiente a un objeto y posterior con la sintaxis de `objeto.método` accedes al valor que posee

Declaras el método en la clase principal y por medio de `extends` en una clase secundaria heredas dicho método, posterior por medio del proceso de instanciación accedes a ese método:

Código:

```
class Element1
{
    methodA():void {
        console.log("Class Element1")
    }
}

class Element2 extends Element1 
{

}

const object = new Element2 
object.methodA()
```

A partir de ahora el objeto `object` podrá acceder al método llamado `methodA`

A nivel de la consola al imprimir a `object` nos daría como resultado **Class Element1**

Answer (score 2):

Haz tu metodo de la otra clase estatico e importa esa clase en el .ts que la vas a usar:

```
class miClase{

   constructor(){

   }

   static metodoAAcceder(){
      console.log("Hola mundo");
   }

}
```

Ahora solo debes llamar desde tu clase en la que usaras ese metodo de esta manera:

```
class miClaseQueUsaElMetodo{

   constructor(){

   }

   ionViewDidEnter(){
       miClase.metodoAAcceder();
   }

}
```